# Copy and modify a shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to "copy" a shared_ptr and modify the contents.

In the following example a "template person" is created and I would like to use it as a "Person" that every body would copy from it. However when std::shared_ptr p2 is assigned the template_person every modification in p2 impacts template_person as well. Is there a way to avoid this, or should I use a normal pointer?

This is my first approach. I want to do this to consume less memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Person{
public:
    ~Person() {}
    Person(int a, std::string b) : age_(a), name_(b) {}

    void set_age(int x) { age_ = x; }
    int age() { return age_; }

private:
    int age_;
    std::string name_;
};

int main () {

    std::shared_ptr<Person> template_person = std::make_shared<Person>(10, "test");

    std::shared_ptr<Person> p2 = template_person;

    p2->set_age(20);

    std::cout << p2->age() << " " << template_person->age() << std::endl;
    //prints 20 20

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would a normal pointer help? Is there a reason you are using a `std::shared_ptr` at all, why not just use `Person template; Person clone = template;`?

Comment: Do you refer to C++14 by C++1y for nostalgic reasons or do you mean something specific?

Comment: @cateof Well, you will either consume memory for one object (shared by two pointers), or consume memory for two objects, which can easch be edited separately. There's no other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of a *shared* pointer. By having a shared pointer to a `Person` instance, you say that `Person` is a shared resource, that is, no matter what `shared_ptr` instance you use to access the resource, you will always be changing *the same* resource.

What you want to achieve is simply copying the `Person` object. Assuming you have an eligible copy constructor (which is trivially true in your case), just get rid of the shared pointers and copy-construct `p2`:

```
int main () {
    Person template_person {10, "test"};

    Person p2 = template_person;

    p2.set_age(20);

    std::cout << p2.age() << " " << template_person.age() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use copy constructor:

```
auto p2 = std::make_shared<Person>(*template_person);
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, there is a good chance, that OP is not entirely sure what he wants and what he needs.

Comment: auto p2 = std::make_shared<Person>(template_person); This one (without the * operator) worked, but I had to add a copy constructor.

Comment: @cateof It won't work without `*`. You can add copy constructor by `Person(const Person&) = default;`

Comment: Person template_person(10, "test");
auto p2 = std::make_shared<Person>(*template_person); fails with no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘Person’)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to have 'deep copy' rather than a 'shared' object.
The smart-pointer acts like the raw-pointer, so the shared resource would change if any change is made through one of the pointer pointing to it.
So please use the copy constructor instead of `std::shared_ptr`.

```
const Person template_person{ 10, "test" };
Person p2 = template_person;
p2.set_age(20);
```